# How to rename an Azure SQL Database using Automation Runbook?

Tags: azure, azure-automation

I created an Azure SQL DB and called it "TempDb". I want to rename it. Can I do it via an automation `Runbook` ? how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While you can achieve that, I really question what is the point of doing so via Automation Runbook? Once you rename it, the second time you try to run the runbook it will fail?

But anyway here is how:

1. Create an Azure Automation Account, if you haven't already
2. Create an automation credential in your Azure Active Directory to use with Azure Automation. You can read [the great tutorial how to do this here](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/08/27/azure-automation-authenticating-to-azure-using-azure-active-directory/).
3. Create your runbook with the following code:

> ```
> workflow RenameSqlDb
> {
>   $cred = Get-AutomationPSCredential -Name "<youraccount>@<yourdomain>.onmicrosoft.com"
>   Add-AzureAccount -Credential $cred
>   Select-AzureSubscription "Subscription name for which this account is valid"
>   Set-AzureSqlDatabase -ServerName <azure_Sql_server_name> -DatabaseName <TempDB> -NewDatabaseName <NewName_for_theDB>
>     Write-Output "Done."
> }
> ```

You can be even more creative by parametrizing the `ServerName`, `DatabaseName` and `NewDatabaseName` parameters.

Note: this is tested workbook that achieves desired result.

Comment: Thanks. The point is performing the operation from within the Azure portal, not having to open firewall to external IPs.

Comment: interesting view. never thought on that, but still somehow valid. But, if you do PowerShell, you can anyway rename the Database without opening ports. PowerShell cmdlets do work over HTTPS with Azure Management Service API. So you don't need to open any ports to any service. Just having a valid Internet connection. Then you can rename the database from any place in the world without any special requirements (besides Internet connection)